# Get ID of Summernote Element

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am going to have multiple summernote fields on a page, and I want a dynamic way to get the element ID when doing onblur. I can't seem to get the elements id, it just comes back *undefined*

Example HTML

`<div class="summernote" id="desc_long" name="Long Description">Test 123</div>`

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        toolbar: [
          ['headline', ['style']],
          ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
          ['alignment', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['insert', ['link']],
        ],
        onblur: function() {
          var objid = $(this).attr("id");
          alert(objid);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i think this here is global object

Comment: access id through event.target

Comment: try printing the this on console and see which object is getting on blur. console.log($(this));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of summernote are you using?? If it's v0.6.5 or greater then use camel case i.e. onBlur and not onblur . Try this and check. Also post what error are you getting,if any. Also, callback function is missing. Check http://summernote.org/deep-dive/

Comment: Thanks for the advise! Was old version.

Answer (score 3):

**callbacks** attr is missing in your  case

```
           $('.summernote').summernote({
                 toolbar: [
                  ['headline', ['style']],
                  ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                  ['color', ['color']],
                  ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                  ['alignment', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                  ['insert', ['link']],
                ],
                callbacks: {
                    onBlur: function( event ) {
                    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
                        //alert("onBlur event triggered!");
                    }
                }
            });
```